# Why does my control disappear on postback?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, tinymce

I have used TinyMCE in update panel but it keeps disappearing after each partial post back, why ? It should work in either case, even official site has no word on it.

I have used it like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#<%=txtBoxBody.ClientID%>',
            height: 200,
            theme: 'modern',
            plugins: [
              'advlist autolink lists pagebreak',
              //'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars fullscreen',
              'insertdatetime save contextmenu directionality',
              ' paste textcolor textpattern print'
            ],
            toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | fontsizeselect | forecolor emoticons | fontselect emoticons | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify',
            //toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons',
            //image_advtab: true,
            fontsize_formats: '8pt 9pt 10pt 11pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 20pt 22pt 24pt 26pt 28pt 36pt 48pt 72pt',
            //templates: [
            //  { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
            //  { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
            //],
            content_css: [
              '//fast.fonts.net/cssapi/e6dc9b99-64fe-4292-ad98-6974f93cd2a2.css',
              '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
            ]
        });


    </script>

on this txtbox 
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBoxBody" Rows="20" Columns="25" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

it appears at first page load but not after post back
UPDATE:

it tried this on pageload event

```
 //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), txtBoxBody.UniqueID + "Add", "tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true,'" + txtBoxBody.ClientID + "');", true);
        //ScriptManager.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this, this.GetType(), txtBoxBody.UniqueID + "Remove", "tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true,'" + txtBoxBody.ClientID + "');");
```

It makes it visible but makes the form full of troubles i.e. full postbacks and different issues.

Update: I have used pageLoad of javascript and put this code inside that but then plugin disappeared.

Update: then I tried what Piyush suggested

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetEditor() {
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#<%=txtBoxBody.ClientID%>',
            height: 200,
            theme: 'modern',
            plugins: [
              'advlist autolink lists pagebreak',
              //'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars fullscreen',
              'insertdatetime save contextmenu directionality',
              ' paste textcolor textpattern print'
            ],
            toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | fontsizeselect | forecolor emoticons | fontselect emoticons | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify',
            //toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons',
            //image_advtab: true,
            fontsize_formats: '8pt 9pt 10pt 11pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 20pt 22pt 24pt 26pt 28pt 36pt 48pt 72pt',
            //templates: [
            //  { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
            //  { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
            //],
            content_css: [
              '//fast.fonts.net/cssapi/e6dc9b99-64fe-4292-ad98-6974f93cd2a2.css',
              '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
            ]
        });


    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // below will execute first time when page load
    SetEditor();

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        // this will execute on partial postback
        SetEditor();
    }
</script>
```

but same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue please follow below steps,

1. Create setEditor javascript function as below,

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function SetEditor() {
       tinymce.init({
       ...
       });
   }
   </script>
   ```
2. before end of body tag, add below script,

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       // below will execute first time when page load
       SetEditor();

       Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

       function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
           // this will execute on partial postback
           SetEditor();          
       }
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Well, I tried with the same and it worked for me. Did you put all these things in .aspx file?

Comment: Have you added second portion of script before end of body tag? Or within head tag, please confirm. It must before end of body tag. Also please confirm one more thing, did you use update panel in aspx page?

Comment: sir: I have used it within the HEAD content Template and yes .aspx has UPDATE panel in it.

Comment: Yes, I suspect that. Read my answer again. You need to put two scripts at different places. First seteditor function, within head content. And other script block before end of body closing tag. If you still can't figure out, can you give me your whole aspx page, I will modify and send to you.

Comment: Sir: I have sent you my code, to your email address because stack overflow won't allow me to post such huge code. Please check your email

Comment: Ok I will take a look and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your init in a function
then make sure to register you init function with the scriptmanager
like example
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, 
         this.Page.GetType(), mce.ClientID, "pageLoad();", true);

Comment: ok it worked but it causes full post back of page at every simle click even

Answer (score 0):

A very much help by @Piyush and little bit modifications did the trick and solved the problem.

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), txtBoxBody.UniqueID + "Add", "tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true,'" + txtBoxBody.ClientID + "');", true);
  ScriptManager.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this, this.GetType(), txtBoxBody.UniqueID + "Remove", "tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true,'" + txtBoxBody.ClientID + "');");
```